# javascript regex tags with full webaddress (text mining, inverse match)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem with inverse match of javascript regex.

Example text:

> Some awsome text with apple, orange and  other
> fruits:https://www.address_nr1.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ. Another piece
> of text www.address_nr2.pl; Last sentence with special characters
> !@#$%^&*().

My regex:

```
/(www|http:|https:)+[^\s]+[\w]|[A-Z0-9]+/gmi
```

I want to inverse match of this regex. If I add `^` in the second part of the regex `(www|http:|https:)+[^\s]+[\w]|[^A-Z0-9]+` I can inverse all correctly without web adrress. How I can inverse webaddress in this situation?

"At the end" I will use google script `(var keywords = text.split(regex))` to push all keyworlds and webaddresses to the array.

EDIT: I added regex flags.

SOLUTION:
Thank you Ryszard Czech. "Rather match, do not split." works perfect.

var keywords = text.matchAll(/(?:www|https?://)\S*\b|[\p{L}0-9]+/gu);
keywords = Array.from(keywords, x => x[0]);

I changed A-Z to \p{L} to capture Polish letters and added the "u" flag because it is necessary with \p{L}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather *match*, do not *split*.

```
/(?:www|https?:\/\/)\S*\b/g
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/3lA17h/1/)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    www                      'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ://                      '://'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S*                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (0 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

JavaScript:

```js
const string = "Some awsome text with apple, orange and other fruits:https://www.address_nr1.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ. Another piece of text www.address_nr2.pl; Last sentence with special characters !@#$%^&*().";
const results = string.matchAll(/(?:www|https?:\/\/)\S*\b/g);
console.log(Array.from(results, x => x[0]));
```